# Add tabindex to text in openui5

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, tabindex

I am using `sap.m.Text` to display a status of a task (failed, success, error, etc..) and I want the status keyboard accessible, but keyboard 'tab' press does not read the status.

The text is a rendered inside `<span>` tag in DOM, is there anyway to add `tabindex="0"` to span while declaration of `sap.m.Text` component itself? or is there any other component of OpenUI5 I can use to show the status which is also keyboard accessible? (I also used `sap.m.Label`, but not getting accessed by keyboard again.

Thank you.

Comment: the displayOnly property suggests, that of not activated the input field is reacheable with tab, look at: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/api/sap.m.Label/controlProperties

Comment: if you provide a working minimal example it will be easier to spot your error and help you fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements can be tabbed to if they can receive focus. To determine which OpenUI5 UI controls can receive focus, look at whether:

- an element in the HTML DOM structure that is rendered by the control's renderer can receive focus (e.g. `sap.m.Button` renders an HTML `<button>`, which can be focused.
- the control's renderer specifically writes the `tabindex` property.

Examples of such controls include `Button`, `Input`, `Link`, and an `ObjectAttribute` that is active (i.e. also a link). So you could, for example, use `ObjectAttribute`, but then your status will look like a hyperlink. To determine the above, you can, for example, search the [OpenUI5 repository](https://github.com/SAP/openui5) online or in your local editor.

If there is no suitable control, you can easily [extend one](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/8dcab0011d274051808f959800cabf9f). For example, you can extend `sap.m.Text`. This should be a simple extension, as you only need to add `tabindex`. Here is an example that is very close to what you'll need to do [Extending Input Rendering](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/bcee26a4801748f39bf5698d83d903aa.html).

Comment: Thank you @rikusv for the answer. I can definitely try extending the `sap.m.Text' and will add tabindex